# How to disable sorting in TreeView?

Tags: asp.net

I have A TreeView in my aspx page as shown below.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" 
            ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="True">
        </asp:TreeView>
```

When I add nodes to this TreeView it always sorts in alphabetical order. What I really want, is the order that I have added the nodes.

Comment: I managed it with prefixing numbers to the name. Any proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this question.  There are some answers here that covers some of the basics of implementing sorting on the TreeView control.

[ASP.NET TreeView sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776162/asp-net-treeview-sort)